# Copy environment variables from one Elastic Beanstalk environment to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a bash command I can run to copy all the environment variables from one AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to another?  I'm trying to copy to a new environment, so assume that the target environment has no environment variables that need removing.

I'm aware of [`eb printenv`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-printenv.html) and [`eb setenv`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-printenv.html), but these were not designed to work together.

Answer (score 2):

You can string them together with a bit of bash magic:

```bash
eb setenv -e <TARGET_ENVIRONMENT> \
`eb printenv <SOURCE_ENVIRONMENT> | \
sed 's/ = /=/' | sed 's/ Environment Variables://'`
```

If you prefer, you can create the following bash function:

```bash
function eb-copy-env {
    # Usage: eb-copy-env <source_environment> <dest_environment>
    test "$1" && test "$2" || { echo "Usage: eb-copy-env <source_environment> <dest_environment>"; return 1; }
    SOURCE_VARS=$(eb printenv $1) || { echo $SOURCE_VARS; return 1; }
    SOURCE_VARS=$(echo $SOURCE_VARS | sed 's/Environment Variables://' | sed 's/ = /=/g')
    echo $SOURCE_VARS
    echo -e "\nBeginning copy"
    eb setenv -e $2 $SOURCE_VARS
    echo -e "\nCopy successful"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849354/401712) gave me the right idea, but didn't quite work for me. Possibly because of a newer `ebcli` version. I have:

```
$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.20.10 (Python 3.11.7 (main, Dec  8 2023, 14:22:46) [GCC 13.2.0])
```

Edit: it was not a problem with the version, but with special characters (in my case, spaces and commas) in the variable values.

The following function supports excluding variables by a `sed` pattern, e.g.
`eb_copy_env env1 env2 PASSWORD=` excludes variables matching "PASSWORD=".

```
eb_copy_env() {
  if [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 SOURCE-ENVIRONMENT TARGET-ENVIRONMENT [EXCLUDE...]"
    return 1
  fi
  local vars
  local exclude
  vars=$(eb printenv "$1") || { echo "$vars"; return 1; }
  # remove header, spaces around the equals sign, and leading spaces
  vars=$(echo "$vars" | sed '/Environment Variables:/d;s/ = /=/;s/ = /=/;s/^ *//')
  # remove some variables
  for exclude in "${@:3}"; do
    echo "Excluding: $exclude"
    vars=$(echo "$vars" | sed "/$exclude/d")
  done
  echo "Setting variables:"
  echo "$vars"
  # replace new lines by space
  vars=$(echo "$vars" | tr '\n' ' ')
  # set variables, split with xargs
  eb setenv --debug --environment "$2" $(echo "$vars" | xargs -n1 echo)
  echo "Done"
}
```

Comment: I'm running on EB CLI 3.20.6, which shouldn't be meaningfully different.  What goes wrong?

Comment: I may have spoken/posted too soon. I think, what goes wrong is special characters and or empty values in the environment variables. I'm getting "ERROR: InvalidSyntaxError - You must use the format KEY=VALUE to set an environment variable. Variables must start with a letter." I thought it was empty lines or the spaces on the start of each line, which I removed with `sed`, but it still fails for me with the same error message (for some variables).

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, it seems impossible to set variables with some special characters. The docs say special characters (it doesn't say which ones exactly) need to be escaped by a backslash. However, that did not work for me for space or comma, so I updated my script to make it easy to exclude some variables. I also needed to delimit multiple variables by space and to split them with xargs for it to finally work. I'll update my answer accordingly.